# Why is this test case (Jest) with a trivial asynchronous callback failing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, timeout, jestjs

#### Context

I am trying to write a test case, using Jest (24.9), that has an asynchronous callback function and will succeed when run.  The test case I wrote seems like it should work, but it is failing, and its not clear to me why.

#### Test Case

This is the test case.  It should wait for about 100 ms and then succeed.

```js
test("async test case", async () => {
    await (new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {expect(true).toBe(true)}, 100);
    }));
}, 10000);
```

#### Error message

When I run the test case, it fails with this error message:

```
: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: 
    at new Spec (C:\Users\<username>\WebstormProjects\jest-async-test\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmine\Spec.js:116:22)
    at new Spec (C:\Users\<username>\WebstormProjects\jest-async-test\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\setup_jest_globals.js:80:9)
    at new JBPatchedSpec (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2019.2.1\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\helpers\jest-intellij\lib\jest-intellij-jasmine-reporter.js:94:7)
    at specFactory (C:\Users\<username>\WebstormProjects\jest-async-test\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmine\Env.js:575:24)
    at Env.it (C:\Users\<username>\WebstormProjects\jest-async-test\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmine\Env.js:644:24)    at Env.it (C:\Users\<username>\WebstormProjects\jest-async-test\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmineAsyncInstall.js:132:23)
    at it (C:\Users\<username>\WebstormProjects\jest-async-test\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmine\jasmineLight.js:93:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<username>\WebstormProjects\jest-async-test\async.test.js:2:25)
    ...
```

#### Questions

Why is this test case failing?

What would be an example of a trivial test case with an asynchronous callback that will succeed?

There are several callbacks in this test case.  Which one is the error message referring to?

Comment: You never `resolve` the promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple error.  As @Emissary pointed out, the Promise is never resolved.  A passing version of the test case looks like this:

```js
test("async test case", async () => {
    await (new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {expect(true).toBe(true)}, 100);
        resolve();
    }));
}, 10000);
```